# C# reading datagridview from one form to another form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have two forms, one contains a datagridview control with a data source from MS Access. Data is properly displayed on the datagridview. First I select a cell in that data grid view, then I obtain the Row Index of the currently selected cell. I use that Row Index in an accessor function (code is in the main form):

```
public String Name
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return dataGridView1.Rows[selrow].Cells[1].Value.ToString(); 
    } 
}
```

selrow contains the row index of the currently selected cell. Next, I click a button "Edit record" and this it displays my 2nd form as a modal form. I want to display the value of the above accessor in a text box, so code goes like this (code is in the 2nd form):

```
private void EditRecord_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CashLoan main = new CashLoan();
    txtEName.Text = main.name;
}
```

But when I try to run and debug, I get this "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index" directed at my accessor function. I can't seem to find the source of the problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Then you are not storing the currently active cell index correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you want show value from main form in the textbox of `Editrecord` form. If so

In `Load` handler you create new instance of main form(`CashLoan`).
And trying read values from empty datagridview(I assume you not filling datagridview with data in the contructor) of main form.

Try pass your value to `EditRecord` form as parameter in contructor:
In EditRecord form:

```
private String _originalValue;
public EditRecord(String originalValue)
{
    _originalValue = originalValue;
}
//Then in Load handler
private void EditRecord_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.txtEName.Text = _originalValue;
}

//In main form
EditRecord frm = new EditRecord(this.name);
frm.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Yes you understood me correctly. Thank you! This solution worked well for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
public String Name
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value.ToString(); 
    } 
}
```

cause i guess you have a problem with the current selected row index. Also it would be possible that your row have only one cell. In that case replace the 1 with a 0 cause index starts at 0 (so 0 = 1, 1 = 2 etc...)

```
dataGridView1.Rows[selrow].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```